# Jenkins apt upgrade error /etc/default/jenkins: --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1: not found

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, jenkins

I have Jenkins runnind on Ubuntu 20.04. Jenkins has config file /etc/default/jenkins which contains directive --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 which according [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/) set Jenkins to listen only on localhost. I dont know what it means. This error throws when I run apt upgrade.

The whole error message says:
**Setting up jenkins (2.277.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jenkins.postinst: 71: /etc/default/jenkins: --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1: not found**

Comment: That looks the the format that would be appropriate as a command line option - did you try to use it verbatim inside the config file, or something like `JENKINS_ARGS="--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1"`?

Comment: Which config file do you mean?

Comment: *"Jenkins has config file /etc/default/jenkins"*

Comment: I dont understand. This should be valid. What you mean?